# Existing online file, curl failling download

Tags: curl, makefile, shapefile

**Given a well working url and existing file :** (can be downloaded using a web browser)

```
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.zip
```

**The following Curl request fails to download it :**

```
curl -o subunits.zip 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.zip'
```

**How to make it works ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download link seems to redirect to another domain.

So try,

```
curl -L 'http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_shp.zip' -o <output-file>
```

The "-L" option to follow the redirects.